# Error: Cannot find module './abc/xyz.js on dev env

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, unix, deployment

I have finally finished my NodeJs bot and deployed it on Digital Ocean Droplet.

After cloning the git repo and npm install, I have tried to run `node my-index-file.js` and got this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './abc/xyz.js'
```

Here is the full error:
[image]
This is the first time I deploy a project on a production env, so I assume it's got to be something with the path on the ubuntu machine vs my PC.

The app works perfectly on my PC.

I have installed it on `root/my-project-folder`, which I assume is also not the best practice, but that's not that important at the moment.

***Edit 1***

Here are the `requires` from `node my-index-file.js`

```
const brandsUrl = require('./URLs.json')
const prepareDataFormat = require('./api/prepareDataFormat')
const WooCommerceApi = require('./api/Api.js')
const {checkIfScrapped , getCategory, getTags} = require('./helpers/getCategory')
```

Here is the `ls -l` output from the Droplet:
[image]

And `ls -l` inside the `api` folder:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the available description of the problem and the given error text, we can assume that the project refers to the file by the specified path and the described name, but does not find it there. perhaps the file itself is missing. the name or path  of the file may not be spelled correctly. look at the specified folder to check it. if you don't understand the reason again, provide screenshots of the folder contents relative to the current file.

Update:
the response after receiving new screenshots. As you can see, the "api" and "Api" is different.

```
const WooCommerceApi = require('./api/Api.js')
```

not same

```
const WooCommerceApi = require('./api/api.js')
```

maybe need rename the file `api.js` to `Api.js`

Comment: the thing is, it runs perfectly on my PC, all files are in place. I will ass some screenshots.

Comment: wow, this is embarrassing...thanks a lot! I guess for some reason my PC isn't casa sensitive where the ubuntu machine is.